# Set ListView row background

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following `ListView`:

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView/>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want to set the background of the second **row** (for example) to red programmatically.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171502/change-background-color-of-listview-row-programmatically-wpf

Thanks
Pradip

Comment: @PradipTripathy I saw, thank you, but this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a similar approach:

```
int index = 1;
ListViewItem row = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
row.BackGround = Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AlternationCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx) to store the index of the row in `AlternationIndex`, and then use a trigger to set the background of the second row (at index 1) to red:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```

`AlternationCount` defines the number of rows to count before restarting to zero. For example, if set to 2, the indexes for the rows will be 0 1 0 1 0 1 ..., allowing you to paint to red only the odd or even rows. Setting it to `MaxValue` will never restart the count, effectively setting `AlternationIndex` to the actual index.

Comment: I want to change the background not in XAML, but dynamically (c#), the "second" row is only for example.

Answer (score -1):

Please clarify one thing here nick. Can you tell me whether you want to just make the color of  the second row to red. If that is the case you can iterate through the list view and then keep a count variable on the top and then when the count == 1 then you can change the list view.background color to red. if you have tried this then can you tell me what happened. Does it ended with error or something or nothing happened.