# How to highlight every second row of listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

Is it possible to highlight every second row in list view with some color? For example I have a listview with data from data table, bound to it. So I want to leave the first row background to be white and then second to be blue (for example), then the third would be white, the fourth blue again and so on. Also I would like this effect to continue automatically when I add new items to list view.

Comment: Google - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132390/set-background-for-selected-item-in-listview?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*From @Tim's comment you could have Googled and got a MS solution from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750769(v=vs.85).aspx) or looked at @Vijay's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132390/set-background-for-selected-item-in-listview?rq=1)...*]

For a different approach. First create a style element in your `ResourceDictionary` or if you don't have a `ResourceDictionary` drop it on the page itself

```
<Style x:Key="alternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
         <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
     <!-- setting row height here --> 
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
</Style>
```

Now set the `ItemContanerStyle` on the actual ListView and set the `AlternationCount` attribute):

```
<ListView Name="recordContainer" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2" >
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <!-- Just a few sample columns -->         
         <GridViewColumn Header="aField" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="anotherField" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="yetAnotherField" />
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
   <!-- Whatever you might have in here -->
</ListView>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for just couldn't find the right answer on google. Thank you!