# wpf change listview row foreground color base on data value

Tags: c#, listview

Hi I have a wpf app with a listview in a grid.  I am trying to change the color of a row base on the data value from that row, but not the entire listview.  can someone point me to the right direction please?  thank you

[edit]

on my window,

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListView Margin="5" Name="lstView">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Version" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Version}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="InstalledDate" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding InstalledDate}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

I have a listview binded to a list of software installed on the system.  i want to check the status for missing and color it red.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: @WBuck, i only have the listview binded to a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change background color of ListView row programmatically (wpf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171502/change-background-color-of-listview-row-programmatically-wpf)